# What is the logo sports team of this D basketball name?

Tags: basketball, collegiate

What is the name of the college sports team, which has this college basketball logo?
I see RMAM are part of the logo text.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to give us any more hints about this - e.g. country, university or professional team, or even just where you found this image?

Comment: hi @PhilipKendall I see RMAM are part of the logo text.